# RoCC Busy Signal Usage

Tags: riscv, rocket-chip

Is there any documentation on how the busy signal in RoCC interface is supposed to be used?

My understanding is that an instruction can be sent to RoCC accelerator when `cmd.ready` is HIGH. What about busy?
Upon sending the RoCC instruction, the core will continue running when `cmd.ready` is seen to be HIGH, regardless the busy status?

I'm working on a project where I will implement TileLink for system memory access as well. I'm trying to figure out how to properly set the busy signal in tandem with direct memory access.